# next and previous arrows don't show up after using

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have my slideshow all set up but when I click the next or previous buttons on the next image the buttons shrink down and become little grey boxes. Does anyone know why this is happening?

PHP/HTML

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if ($_POST['action'] == 'Previous') {
        $index = $_POST['i'];
        if ($index == 0) {
            $index = count($pic_array) - 1;
            echo "<div class='slide'>
                     <img src= ".$dir.$pic_array[$index]." />
                     <div class='slide-caption'>
                        <h3 class='slide-title'> $titles[$index] </h3>
                        <p class='des'> $descriptions[$index] </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>";
        }
        else {
            $index--;
            echo "<div class='slide'>
                     <img src= ".$dir.$pic_array[$index]." />
                     <div class='slide-caption'>
                        <h3 class='slide-title'> $titles[$index] </h3>
                        <p class='des'> $descriptions[$index] </p>
                     </div>";
        }
        echo "<form action='gallery.php' method='post'>
            <div class='previous'>
                <button value='Previous' name='action'>
                    <i class='fa fa-arrow-left fa-2x'></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class='next'>
                <button value='Next' name='action'>
                    <i class='fa fa-arrow-right fa-2x'></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br>
           <input type='hidden'  name='i' value= '$index'>
           </form>";

    }
    if ($_POST['action'] == "Next") {
        $index = $_POST['i'];
        if ($index == count($pic_array) - 1) {
            $index = 0;
            echo "<div class='slide'>
                     <img src= ".$dir.$pic_array[$index]." />
                     <div class='slide-caption'>
                        <h3 class='slide-title'> $titles[$index] </h3>
                        <p class='des'> $descriptions[$index] </p>
                     </div>";
        }
        else {
            $index++;
            echo "<div class='slide'>
                     <img src= ".$dir.$pic_array[$index]." />
                     <div class='slide-caption'>
                        <h3 class='slide-title'> $titles[$index] </h3>
                        <p class='des'> $descriptions[$index] </p>
                     </div>";
        }
        echo "<form action='gallery.php' method='post'>
            <div class='previous'>
                <button value='Previous' name='action'>
                    <i class='fa fa-arrow-left fa-2x'></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class='next'>
                <button value='Next' name='action'>
                    <i class='fa fa-arrow-right fa-2x'></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br>
             <input type='hidden'  name='i' value= '$index'>
             </form>";
    }

} else {
    $index = 1;
    echo '<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>';
    echo "<div class='slide'>
            <img src= ".$dir.$pic_array[$index]." />
            <div class='slide-caption'>
                <h3 class='slide-title'> $titles[$index] </h3>
                <p class='des'> $descriptions[$index] </p>
            </div>";
    echo "<form action='gallery.php' method='post'>
            <div class='previous'>
                <button value='Previous' name='action'>
                    <i class='fa fa-arrow-left fa-2x'></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class='next'>
                <button value='Next' name='action'>
                    <i class='fa fa-arrow-right fa-2x'></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type='hidden'  name='i' value= '$index'>
           </form>";
}
```

CSS

```
.slide {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
}
.slide img {

    display:block;
    max-width:100%;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
 }
.slide-title {
    margin:0 6rem 1rem;
}
.des {
    margin: 0 6rem 0;
}
.slide-caption {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
    opacity:0;
}
.previous {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.next {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Javascript

$(function() {

```
$slide = $('.slide');
$caption = $slide.find('.slide-caption');
$next = $slide.find('.next');
$previous = $slide.find('.previous');

$slide.hover(function() {
        $caption.css('opacity', '1');
        $next.css('opacity', '1');
        $previous.css('opacity', '1');
    }, function() {
        $caption.css('opacity', '0');
        $next.css('opacity', '0');
        $previous.css('opacity', '0');
    }
);
```

});

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeF9F.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXL1K.png

Comment: Can you post images before and after click the button? And what is inside "$pic_array"?

Comment: I just posted the link to what it looks like. Inside of $pic_array are the file names, it's not important to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing things the hard way, but I understand why it looked like the correct approach at first.

Instead of echoing out all your HTML from PHP, do just what you need in PHP and do the rest in HTML and javascript. You seem to be using Bootstrap, so we will use the Bootstrap carousel *(aka slider.)*.

**First step is for you to do:** At top, write PHP code to grab all the images (just the `paths/names.ext`) for your slider and put them into a PHP array, which the code below will convert into JSON and store invisibly on the page as a string inside a hidden `<input>` field. The javascript/jQuery will then grab that string, turn it into a javascript array, and use that to populate your slider. *Slick as frog's hair.*

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6acrL6m7/)</kbd>

```
<?php
    $arrPics = your_php_fn_to_get_all_images_from_database_or_filesystem_as_an_array();
    //$arrPics = array('["http://loremflickr.com/500/98","http://loremflickr.com/500/100","http://loremflickr.com/498/100","http://loremflickr.com/498/98","http://loremflickr.com/499/99"]');
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <input id="jsonPics" type="hidden" value="<?php echo json_encode($arrPics); ?>" />

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"></div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div><!-- #myCarousel -->
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    var arrPix = $('#jsonPics').val();
    var arrPix = $.parseJSON( arrPix );
    //alert( arrPix.length );
    $carItem = $('.carousel-inner');
    $carInd =  $('.carousel-indicators');
    $.each(arrPix, function(i, pic){
        $carInd.append('<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="' +i+ '"></li>');
        $carItem.append('<div class="item"><img src="' +pic+ '" alt="Slider Image"></div>');
    });
    $('.carousel-indicators li:first-of-type').addClass('active');
    $('.carousel-inner .item:first-of-type').addClass('active');

});//END document.ready
```

---

Note:

The above jsFiddle demo fakes out the PHP part (jsFiddle cannot do PHP) and begins with the hidden input field populated with the JSON "array" that you need to get from PHP, as per the code at top.

*That part hasn't been tested/debugged, so that is left as an exercise for you. Of course, if you have trouble with it, post a new question here on StackOverflow - but try hard to figure it out yourself first.*

Comment: I know I'm doing things the hardway. I have to do training tasks for a job and I've already completed this using Jquery for most things. I just need to finish this which I left to do after I already completed it the other way,

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap (are you?) you should be able to just cut/paste the code. *All ya gadda do* is to delete the old echo out code and refactor as above. Seriously: give it a try. Compare what you had with what I did. VERY FAST to change it once you understand how I did it (not too hard, really). Backup existing file and allot 15 mins to see how far you get, and ***I'll bet*** you'll be shocked how far you do get. *Otherwise, you've potentially got a few hours of on-desk-head-banging -- so it's definitely worth giving it a "let's see how far I can get" try*

Comment: I don't really know why I'm using bootstrap for the arrows, I could just pull a picture of a left and right arrows correct? I can't cut and paste the code because I'm supposed to use GET/POST methods for the first part of the task and modify it to then use jquery/ajax which I've already done and I'm coming back to finish this up. I just need to know why the arrows don't show up after next or previous have been clicked.

Comment: B'strap is a layout framework *(all about [the grid](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp))* that comes with a number of built-in capabilities, one of which is the carousel. I just suggested that since the library is loaded, why not use [the built-in carousel?](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) Would love to help more, but out of time. Good luck with this.